# What does the NPTR exactly do and why it's not compiling in c?

Tags: c, pointers, null

Based on some codes I found from stack overflow, I wrote the following codes:

```
char *split[NPTR] = { NULL }, **p = split;
```

I do not quite understand why the first variable should be in a char array that has `NPTR` with assigned `{NULL}`. Is there anything different from `char *split[] = NULL`?

Also, when I run the code, the codes spit out the error below:

```
error: NPTR' undeclared (first use in this function)
note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Comment: Looks like there should be a `#define NPTR x` where `x` is the Number of PoinTeRs to define. Can you link the SO post you used as a reference?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found `#define NPTR 32     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */` was included in, so I assume that there will be 32 possible pointers for this `NPTR`? 
The link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148561/how-can-i-parse-the-command-line-with-semicolons/61149850#61149850

Answer (score 0):

```
char *split[] = NULL
```

It's invalid initialization

```
char *split[NPTR] = { NULL };
```

It means, split is an array that content of `NPTR` pointers. Each pointer is initialized by NULL.

```
#define NPTR 32
```

In your comment, it means we define `NPTR = 32` as a constant value.

See the code below to understand more:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// define NPTR = 3;
#define NPTR 3

int main()
{
    char * split[NPTR] = {NULL};
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
       if(split[i] == NULL)
            printf("ptr[%d] = NULL\n", i);
    }
    split[0] = "abc";
    split[1] = "cdf";
    split[2] = "ijk";

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", split[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
ptr[0] = NULL                                                                                                           
ptr[1] = NULL                                                                                                           
ptr[2] = NULL                                                                                                           
abc                                                                                                                     
cdf                                                                                                                     
ijk
```